# Designing an attendance database: Is it good practice to use employees as fields?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a very simple attendance tracking database, actually this will be my very first database. There are about 30 employees, everyone has a unique id. Every few months, someone quits and there will be some newcomers. The only thing need to be recorded everyday is their attendance status:attendance,absence or leave.

I am thinking to use only one table, the fields are employees' id, and rows represents days, values are either 0,1 or 2. I think this is pretty much it. But one thing I don't feel good is when someone joins, I will have to add a new field for him. In my past experience, a table's fields are always stable, only records are being changed. This makes me wonder whether the design on my mind is a good idea, and if not, what is a good design for this?

Comment: this is a bad design decision

Comment: I will propose one. Someone else do so first if ya want.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following schema to start. The tables are mere stubs of course.

```
create schema xyz837_testdb;    -- create a test db so as not to clutter yours
use xyz837_testdb;  -- use new db just created

-- drop table users;
create table users
(   userId int auto_increment primary key,
    userName varchar(100) not null,
    status char(1) not null, -- dream up some code / FK to a code table?
    endEmploymentDate date null -- date employment ended
);

-- drop table attendance;
create table attendance
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    userId int not null,
    workDate date not null,
    dayWorkStatus char(1) not null, -- dream up some code / FK to a code table?
    hoursWorked decimal(4,2) not null, -- test this for overflows (errors). Seems fine
    unique index (userId,workDate),
    index (workDate), -- remember, left-most indexes are mostly of value
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(userId) -- referential integrity
);
```

Test it:

```
insert attendance(userId,workDate,dayWorkStatus,hoursWorked) values
(3,'2016-01-04','w',11.22) -- fails FK contraint. User 3 is not in system. Error 1452

-- Add users 1 to 4 relying on auto_increment for userId
insert users(userName,status,endEmploymentDate) values
('Guy who quit','I','2015-10-31'),
('John Henry','A',null),
('Sally Higgins','A',null),
('Kate Macintosh','A',null);

-- Insert some attendance rows
insert attendance(userid,workdate,dayWorkStatus,hoursWorked) values
(3,'2016-01-04','w',11.22), -- works fine now. Users exist
(2,'2016-01-05','w',8),  
(3,'2016-01-05','w',9/25);  

insert attendance(userid,workdate,dayWorkStatus,hoursWorked) values
(3,'2016-01-04','w',11.22) --  Error 1062: Duplicate entry. good error to have. It means you keep your data clean.
```

Query Test:

```
select u.userId,u.userName,ifnull(a.hoursWorked,0) as hoursWorked 
from users u 
left join attendance a 
on u.userId=a.userId   and a.workDate='2016-01-05' 
where u.status='A'; 

+--------+----------------+-------------+
| userId | userName       | hoursWorked |
+--------+----------------+-------------+
|      2 | John Henry     |        8.00 |
|      3 | Sally Higgins  |        9.25 |
|      4 | Kate Macintosh |        0.00 |
+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

The query test skips Inactive workers, and with the left join, picks up active workers that did not have attendance reported (0 hours worked) in the `attendance` table. So, for those cases of no attendance reported, the left join returns a null which is converted to a 0.

Cleanup test:

```
drop schema xyz837_testdb;  -- drop db just created
```

Note the referential integrity in the `attendance` table using [Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Also, the `attendance` table has a **unique** composite key. That way a user/date combo cannot occur twice. So a repeat combo will fail on an insert. Rather, use an update statement to modify one or two columns.

As for user insert, see the manual page on [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Comment: To confirm whether I understand the schema correclty: If there are 30 employees, everyday the attendance table will have 30 new records, right?

Comment: That could be a way, sure. It depends on your queries (left joins in particular) to get at all the data. Which includes workers that did not work but who are user.status='a' for active

Comment: So if you only want to track workers that showed up, maybe there are 19 rows in the attendance table for a given day with a pool of 30 active workers on your payroll.

Comment: But for the other 11 workers who are not in, I need to know whether they ask for leave  or just being  absence.

Comment: we start now to get into querying. I can gladly assist with that. Beyond the scope of the question. You can ask me all day long if you want in our [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat room. Well, within reason :p

Comment: A Query Test part was added to the answer.